# Case Disagreement: Noun and its Adjective

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Я предпочита́ю зелёный чай чёрному.

In this sentence зелёный [nominative] should be зелёного [accusative] because чай is the direct object and therefore in accusative.

I came across this sentence and want to know if they made a mistake or if there is a grammatical reason which I am not aware of?

Comment: Is your question about why is it **зелёный** and not **зелёного** OR why **чёрному** does not agree with **чай**? Anyway, I answered both below.

Comment: "Зелёный" is accusative (for inanimate nouns).

Comment: @SergeySlepov My mistake, I should have mentioned that I know why чёрному is the way it is [because it is in dative].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sentence is grammatically sound. The reason for the apparent disagreement is the following.

The verb **предпочитать** takes two objects:

- a direct object in the accusative (зелёный чай)
- an optional indirect object in the dative (чёрному [чаю])

For inanimate masculine gender objects, the accusative coincides with the the nominative (зелёный чай) and not genitive (зелёного чая) as it does for animate objects.

The sentence employs an ellipsis that omits the word [чаю] after **чёрному** like in the English example: *John likes black tea and Mary likes green* [tea].

Hope this helps clear up the confusion.

Comment: A nitpick: *предпочитать* doesn't strictly *require* two objects; the dative one is optional. You can just say *я предпочитаю зеленый чай*

Comment: @Wilson, thanks! Edited my answer.

Comment: @Thank you, Sergey! You cleared up my confusion with a great simple explanation.